# Get full value from array using partial value

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array like this:

```
var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];
```

Now I want to get the number at the end of a particular value. For example I want to search the array for `"md-"` and see what number is at the end of that string (should return 4).

I can't do `array.indexOf("xs-")` because that isn't the whole value. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, you could just use a regular old `for` loop, or you could use `.filter` for example. Will there only ever been one matching element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method that takes the prefix you're looking for, the array, and the split character and returns all the numbers in an array:

```
function findNumberFromPrefix(prefix, arr, splitChar) {
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
            values.push(arr[i].split(splitChar)[1]);
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

And call it:

```
var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];
var values = findNumberFromPrefix("md-", array, "-");

console.log(values); //["4"]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rn4h9msh/

Comment: Thanks, the function packages it all together nicely. Lots of other good suggestions in this thread though!

Answer (score 5):

Using a for loop:

```js
var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];
var search = "md-";
var found = null;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].indexOf(search) === 0) {
    found = array[i];
    break;    // Note: this is assuming only one match exists - or at least you are
              // only interested in the first match
  }
}
if (found) {
  alert(found);
} else {
  alert("Not found");
}
```

Using `.filter`:

```js
    var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];
    var search = "md-";

    var filtered = array.filter(function(item) {
      return item.indexOf(search) === 0;
    });

    // note that here filtered will contain all matched elements, so it might be more than
    // one match.
    alert(filtered);
```

Building from @János Weisz's suggestion, you can easily transform your array into an object using .reduce:

```js
        var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];
        var search = "md";

        var obj = array.reduce(function(prev, item) {
          var cells = item.split("-");
          prev[cells[0]] = cells[1];
          return prev;
        }, {});

         // note: at this point we have an object that looks like this:
         // { xs:1, sm:10, md: 4 }
         // if we save this object, we can do lookups much faster than looping 
         // through an array
         // now to find "md", we simply do:

        alert(obj[search]);
```

If you need to do multiple look ups from the same source array, then transforming it into an object may be the most efficient approach overall. You pay the initial price of the transformation, but after than lookups are `O(1)` versus `O(n)` for each time you have to search your array. Of course, if you only ever need one item, then probably don't bother.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using objects for this:

```
var array = [{'type': 'xs', 'value': 1}, {'type' : 'sm', 'value': '10'}, {'type' : 'md', 'value': '4'}];
```

This way you can search the array as:

```
function searchMyArrayByType(array, type) {
    var items[];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i].type == type) items.push(array[i].value);
    }

    return items;
}

var valuesWithMd = searchMyArrayByType(array, 'md');
```

For more information regarding the structure and use of objects, please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Unfortunately the array is created dynamically, so forming it into a useful object like this would add more steps.

Comment: @Coop It's pretty simple, actually: `array.push({'type': 'newtype',  'value': 1})`. If you need further help with that (for example, creating the objects from a PHP echo), please don't hesitate to ask on this site, althought I'm sure this is answered already.

Comment: @Coop: You can use `.reduce` to simply map the array into an object indexed by the prefix. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A more *functional* approach and assuming you can have have more than one element with the same prefix:

```
function findPrefix(array, prefix) {
  return array.filter(function (a) { return a.indexOf(prefix) === 0; })
    .map(function (e) { return e.slice(prefix.length); })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one matching element, do a loop like this:

```
var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];
var needle = "md-";
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  if(array[i].indexOf(needle) == 0)
    alert(array[i].substr(needle.length, array[i].length));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kg0c43ov/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
var array = ["xs-1", "sm-10", "md-4"];

getValue("md-");

function getValue(search) {
    for(var key in array) {
        if(array[key].indexOf(search) > -1) {
            alert("Array key is: " + key);
            alert("Array value is: " + array[key].replace(search, ""));
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3wcyrby5/2/)